# Is there an IoT device which has Bluetooth, GPS, a USB port and which can support a module for an alarm?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, gps, wearables

I'm looking for an IoT device which has Bluetooth, GPS, a USB port and which can support a module for an alarm. The end product is a wearable device therefore the device should be small.

It should be something like an Arduino or a Raspberry Pi. The size should be as small as possible but it should be compatible with all the above mentioned features.

Comment: What sort of device are you specifically looking for? To be able to answer this, you should really specify exactly what type of device you want (do you want a board that you can program and put into a case?). Do you also know  more exact dimensions that you need to help narrow down the search?

Answer (score 5):

SIMCOM [SIM808](http://simcom.ee/modules/gsm-gprs-gnss/sim808/) module seems to meet the requirements for your device.

> **Bluetooth:** compliant with 3.0+EDR
>
> **Specification for GPS**
>
> Receiver type
>
> - 22 tracking /66 acquisition -channel
> - GPS L1 C/A code
>
> Sensitivity
>
> - Tracking: -165 dBm
> - Cold starts : -147 dBm
>
> Time-To-First-Fix
>
> - Cold starts: 30s (typ.)
> - Hot starts: 1s (typ.)
> - Warm starts: 28s (typ.)
>
> Accuracy
>
> - Horizontal position : <2.5m CEP
>
> **USB interface**

Moreover, as you are planning for a wearable device, it offers following advantages:

> - Dimensions: 24.0*24.0*2.6mm
> - Weight: 3.30g
> - Low power consumption
> - Supply voltage range 3.4 ~ 4.4V

Comment: Side note: special attention should payed when buying this module, because some of them has only GSM/GPRS support by default and firmware upgrade is needed to enable Bluetooth or/and GPS functionalities.

Answer (score 3):

*Shameless plug*
In about a years time you can get an nRF91 + nRF52840 combo. LTE(CATM1 and NbIoT), GPS, BLE, USB, 802.15.4, etc, that uses a fraction of the power of current devices, and got plenty of µC-resources to spare.